# Transpose JSON in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We have a column in BigQuery that stored the JSON data below and I need to dynamically parse it. It's my first time to work in a JSON format and We need to transpose it (for reference please see the Expected output below). Here's a sample of a JSON data. I need to transpose any value under the changed_happened

Sample JSON:

```json
  "changed_happened":[
      [
         "company_name",
         null,
         "test"
      ],
      [
         "conversion",
         "1.21810222123",
         "1.65272222"
      ],
      [
         "base_total",
         "$ 12,000.000",
         "$ 1,0000"
      ],
      [
         "base_net_total",
         "$ 12,100,00",
         "$ 1,100.00"
      ],
      [
         "total",
         "\u00a3 5,000.00",
         "\u00a3 2,000.00"
      ],
      [
         "net_total",
         "5,000.00",
         "3,000.00"
      ],
      [
         "net_total",
         0.0,
         "2,500.00"
      ],
      [
         "tax",
         0.0,
         "$ 1,652.70"
      ],
      [
         "grand_total",
         "$ 12,181.02",
         "$ 1,652.70"
      ],
      [
         "words",
         "SGD Twelve Thousand, One Hundred And Eighty One and Two Cent only.",
         "SGD One Thousand, Six Hundred And Fifty Two and Seventy Cent only."
      ],
      [
         "total",
         "\u00a3 10,000.00",
         "\u00a3 1,000.00"
      ],
      [
         "words",
         "GBP Ten Thousand only.",
         "GBP One Thousand only."
      ],
      [
         "outstading",
         "$ 10,000.00",
         "$ 1,652.70"
      ],
      [
         "release_dt",
         null,
         ""
      ]
```

Expected Output: `Company Name | Conversion | base_total | base_total | total`

Comment: How is this a BigQuery question?  You have just provided JSON data without describing where it comes from.

Comment: it comes from Big Query and stored in a column and I need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but I think the solution is something akin to:

```sql
select * except(your_json_col) from (
  select your_json_col, 
    json_value(arr, '$[0]') header, 
    json_value(arr, '$[1]') r1,
    json_value(arr, '$[2]') r2
  from your_table,
  unnest(json_extract_array(your_json_col)) arr
)
pivot(any_value(value) for header in ('company_name', 'conversion', 'base_total', 'base_net_total', ............))
```

See the docs for:

- [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator)
- [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array)